# Javascript JSON Insert new row after 3 items returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am using a Google sheet to populate data on my website, relevant to a league I am part of. Everything is working great, except for one very tiny aspect. I've been searching online for a way to do this and can't seem to find a resource that gives me an way to do it.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 on the site, and using Cards to display my data.  Using the `Card-Deck` feature, I am trying to build a group of rosters, by team, so the league players can see who is on a team.  This works as intended and builds a single row of cards.  What I want to do is only have 3 cards in a row though, as it really squishes the data with any more than that, and we have leagues with up to 16 teams.

Here is my javascript:

```js
// make JSON call to Google Data API
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

  //Build the Card Group
  var cardstart = '';
  cardstart += '<div class="card-deck">';

  var cardend = '';
  cardend += '</div>';

  //Build the Sunday Juniors Rosters
  var sunjunroster = '';

  //Loop to build the html output for team name
  var entrysunjunroster = data.feed.entry;
  for (var ia = 0; ia < entrysunjunroster.length; ia++) {
    if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$night']['$t'] == "sunday" && entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$format']['$t'] == "juniors") {
      sunjunroster += '<div class="card border border-dark mb-3">';
      sunjunroster += '<h4 class="card-header bg-bcaprimary text-light text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$teamname']['$t'] + '</h4>';
      sunjunroster += '<div class="card-body p-0">';
      sunjunroster += '<table class="table table-sm mb-0 tablesorter table-striped"><tbody>';
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p1']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p1']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p2']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p2']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p3']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p3']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p4']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p4']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p5']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p5']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p6']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p6']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p7']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p7']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p8']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p8']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p9']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p9']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p10']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p10']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p11']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p11']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p12']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p12']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p13']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p13']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p14']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p14']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p15']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p15']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      if (entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p16']['$t'] !== '') {
        sunjunroster += '<tr><td class="text-center">' + entrysunjunroster[ia]['gsx$p16']['$t'] + '</td></tr>';
      }
      sunjunroster += '</tbody></table></div></div>';
    }
  }

  // output html - Sunday Juniors 
  $('.sunjunroster').html(cardstart + sunjunroster + cardend);

});
```

And the html to build this on my page:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="sunjunroster"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know with PHP you can count the items returned in your query and insert a line of code, and then continue with the query.  That is what I'd like to do here.

Where it would pick up the count, and after 3 items, it closes the col and row divs, and adds them back in to start a new row.

So it would insert this code:

```html
</div></div><div class="row"><div class="col">
```

and then continue building from the JSON array.

Comment: I'm still learning javascript/jquery, can you explain where I would add this?

I think if I read what you are saying, I should use this:

if ( var ia %3 == 0; ) {
sunjunroster += '</div></div><div class="row"><div class="col">'; }

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator `%`. It returns the remainder of a division. The remainder of an integer dividable by 3 is always 0 so we can use this to our advantage.

```
for (var ia = 0; ia < entrysunjunroster.length; ia++) {
   if (ia % 3 == 0 && ia > 0)
   {
        sunjunroster += '</div></div><div class="row"><div class="col">';
   }
   else if (ia == 0) //expection for zero index, nothing to close
   {
        sunjunroster += '<div class="row"><div class="col">';
   }

   //rest of your code...
}
```

Comment: I've tried implementing this, but it seems to return 1 item for the first row, and then 2 items in the second and doesn't close the row after, but starts a new row, in the same place.

Comment: True, visualized this in my head, makes it more difficult then to actually see what happens on screen, the update should work.

Comment: Almost perfect.  I had to remove the ! at the end of the second line to get it to work.  Demo here:  https://www.westmibcapl.com/leagues/

Click on the Team Rosters in the upper right corner to see the panel it's in.

Comment: Simple typo the !

Comment: I've started cascading this to the rest of my queries, and I found another anomaly.

On my Tuesday GR Teams section on the above demo link, there are 6 teams.  It's returning 1 in the first row, 3 in the second, and 2 in the third.

I thought maybe adding another else if and checking if the value is >= 2 when divided by 3 would correct it, but then I realized that is just repeating the qualifier of >0.